# Data for Flutter Page not loading when routing via MaterialPageRoute, but Hot Reloading loads the data correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, routes

I'm building a Flutter app, and have a page with a table that is populated with data. I load the data like so:

```
class _AccountMenuState extends State<AccountMenu> { {
  List<Account> accounts;

  Future<List<Account>> getAccounts() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://localhost:5000/accounts/' + globals.userId);
    return jsonDecode(response);
  }

  setAccounts() async {
    accounts = await getAccounts();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    setAccounts();
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

This works as expected when hot reloading the page, but when I route to this page via MaterialPageRoute,

like so: `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AccountMenu()));`

then the data is not there.

What am I missing? I thought `initState()` gets called whenever a page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `setState` inside `initState` directly but you can wrap the initialization inside a `PostFrameCallback` to make sure that the `initState` lifecycle of the `Widget` is done.

```
    class _AccountMenuState extends State<AccountMenu> { {
      List<Account> accounts;
    
      Future<List<Account>> getAccounts() async {
        final response = await http.get('http://localhost:5000/accounts/' + globals.userId);
        return jsonDecode(response);
      }
    
      setAccounts() async {
        accounts = await getAccounts();
        setState(() {})
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setAccounts());
        super.initState();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

initState() will not wait for setAccounts() to finish execution. In the method setAccounts() call setState after loading data.

```
 setAccounts() async {
    accounts = await getAccounts();
    setState((){});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

initState does not await. It only loads functions before the widget builder but it does not await.
you need to await loading widgets with data until accounts.length is not empty.
Show loading widget while data still loads or use FutureBuilder

```
List<Account> accounts;

@override
  void initState() {
    setAccounts();
    super.initState();
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 accounts.length > 0 ? SHOW_DATA_HERE : LOADING_WIDGET_HERE
}
```